# Convert javascript datetime object to the format acceptable by highcharts Date.UTC(2014, 0, 2)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having datetime object in the following format: `2014-06-24 20:41:18` but Highcharts Date.UTC expects the date as this: `Date.UTC(2014, 0, 2)`.

What would be the recommended way to convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm having datetime object in the following format: 2014-06-24 20:41:18

That isn't a "datetime object", it's a string. Don't use the Date constructor to parse strings, it calls Date.parse which is known to be inconsistent in browsers, even for strings that conform to the format in ECMA-262 ed 5.

> but Highcharts Date.UTC expects the date as this: Date.UTC(2014, 0, 2)

If you only want to use the date part, and for it to be treated as UTC, you can do:

```
// Provide a string like 2014-06-23
function parseYMD(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2]));
}
```

if you want to include the time (and again it's UTC), change the last line to:

```
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]));
```

which will work reliably in all browsers in use. Note that in ISO 8601, dates without a timezone should be treated as local, not UTC.

Please note that an ISO 8601 like string without a timezone will be treated as UTC in some browsers, as local in some others, and NaN in the rest.